# WPF touchscreen controls

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

I have a ListBox with some items, the user scrolls items and is able to press on someone. The problem is:
I use touch input (Pointer Device/touch frame) and I have this event for press: StylusUp="btnSearch_Click" and every time user tries to scroll items, btnSearch_Click fires. I've tried MouseButtonsEvents either.
Please help!^^

Comment: Why would you use the stylus up event to click the button? That is going to fire every time the user lifts their finger off the control... You can't use the item selection changed event?

Comment: @ron-beyer it also fires, every touch on any item fires SelectionChangedEventArgs